# Why is there a "riding" in "Little Red Riding Hood"?

Tags: names

I get the *little*, the *red* and the *hood*... but how does the *riding* fit in there?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a definition of a riding hood from [Webster's Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/riding+hood):

> Riding hood.
>       (a) A hood formerly worn by women when riding.
>       (b) A kind of cloak with a hood.

Comment: OK thanks! I wouldn't have guessed there is somethink like a "riding hood"

Comment: Yeah, they are most likely obsolete (though I'm not an expert on the history of clothing), at least in terms of being needed for riding/travel.

Comment: *Riding* fits in the name because she is wearing the formal hooded cloak that a woman rider would wear back in those days.

Answer (score 12):

The original German title of the fairy tale, "Rotkaeppchen", has no connotations with riding gear. This only got in when it was translated into English. The literal translation of the fairy tale title would be "Little red hat" (or cap).

Comment: A reasonable explanation would be that the `Riding` was added to form an alliteration, making it sound better and more memorable.

Comment: It seems that the most literal translation seems to be "skullcap".

Comment: I think in the fashion of the times that Rotkaeppchen is set, the English equivalent would have been "bonnet".